# Extracting json dict from POST request

Tags: python, json, django, django-forms, django-views

I want to make use of webhook provided by Townscript to update the is_paid field in my model.
 The format of the data is (a json dict):- [link](https://townscript-api.readme.io/docs/get-notified-on-your-server-regarding-new-registra)(Under server notification API column).
 A piece of useful information on the link was:
 *We will send the data in following format using post parameter **data**.*
Here is the python code:

```
def payment(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        posts=request.POST["data"]

        result=json.dumps(posts) #converting incoming json dict to string
        paymentemail(result)    # emailing myself the string (working fine)

        data = posts
        try:
            user = Profile.objects.filter(email=data['userEmailId']).first()
            user.is_paid = True
            user.save()
        except Exception as e: paymentemail(str(e))   # emailing myself the exception

        return redirect('/home')

    else:
        .......
```

The two emails correspoinding to the **paymentemail()** function in the above code were:

```
"{\"customQuestion1\":\"+9175720*****\",\"customAnswer205634\":\"+917572******\",
    \"customQuestion2\":\"**** University\",\"customQuestion205636\":\"College Name\",\"ticketPrice\":**00.00,
    \"discountAmount\":0.00,\"uniqueOrderId\":\"***********\",\"userName\":\"********\",
    \"customQuestion205634\":\"Contact Number\",\"eventCode\":\"**********\",\"registrationTimestamp\":\"12-12-2019 22:22\",
        \"userEmailId\":\"***********@gmail.com\",etc....}"
```

I understand that the backslashes are for escaping the quotation marks.
Second email: (which is the exception)

```
string indices must be integers
```

Does that mean that data=request.POST['data'] gives me a string thus leading to an error when I use data['userEmailId']? How do I deal with this error?

Comment: maybe `request.POST["data"]` is a string, and you are assinging it to `data`, and when you are trying `data['userEmailId']`, it is throwing the error. Try to remove that try except, so that you can pinpoint the error.

Comment: @NalinDobhal the python app is deployed on heroku, and this particular function only runs when someone registers for the event. So, I guess emailing myself the exception is one of the way to know what kind of errors has occured. If I'm right removing the try and except statement won't work for me as the app is deployed and I can't test it on local server. As far as I know request.POST['data'] should return a json dict as stated on the townscript website, but certainly by using request.POST['data'] I'm not getting what I want. What should I do if data turns out to be a string instead?

Comment: Check whether the data is json or string. As it shows here, the data is string, you can use the python `json` package

Answer (score 0):

```
def payment(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        posts=request.POST
        result=json.dumps(posts) #converting incoming json dict to string
        paymentemail(result)    # emailing myself the string (working fine)
        try:
            user = Profile.objects.filter(email=posts['userEmailId']).first()
            user.is_paid = True
            user.save()
        except Exception as e: paymentemail(str(e))   # emailing myself the exception

        return redirect('/home')

    else:
        .......
```

I changed `posts=request.POST["data"]` since the will get only the value of key "data", instead I use `posts=request.POST` so that we will get the entire request as key-value pair (dict). 
`user = Profile.objects.filter(email=posts['userEmailId']).first()`